# Regarding: jquery.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #mobile-menu-toggle, #mobile-menu a[href*=#]

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am very new to Wordpress and my boss gives me a problem to solve in Wordpress...

```
jquery.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #test-tag
```

Can anybody give me a clue about what it means. Code is too huge to post here.

Comment: U have a selector like `#mobile-menu-toggle, #mobile-menu a[href*=#]` in your code, show that part in the question

Comment: wat do you mean by selector. can you give an example  @ArupRakshit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `#` in the `href` must be escaped with 2 backslashes

```
#test-tag a[href*=\\#]
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/